# Control or change the top, mid, and bottom marker style of Excel::Writer::XLSX::Chart::Stock charts in Python

Tags: python

We are using the Excel::Writer::XLSX::Chart::Stock to create a stock chart of performance timings. Everything works, but we want to change the marker shape and color from the defaults to the ones we control. Below is an excerpt of our code. How do we change the markers from auto to top/red/diamond, middle/red/circle, and bottom/green/square?

```
    chart = workbook.add_chart({"type": "stock"})
    column_index_range = range(
        min_mean_max_dataframe_column_count - 2,
        min_mean_max_dataframe_column_count + 1,
    )
    for column_index in column_index_range:
        series = {
            "name": [sheet_name, starting_row, column_index],
            "categories": [
                sheet_name,
                starting_row + 1,
                0,
                starting_row + 11,
                0,
            ],  # Exclude Average Column
            "values": [
                sheet_name,
                starting_row + 1,
                column_index,
                starting_row + 11,
                column_index,
            ],
            "marker": {"type": "automatic", "size": 4},
        }
        chart.set_high_low_lines(
            {
                "line": {"width": 2},
            },
        )
        chart.add_series(series)
```

Did a search on GitHub for set_high_low_lines examples. Search Google for variations of Excel::Writer::XLSX::Chart::Stock and markers. I have reviewed the source code for the Python package. We could not find anything in detail about how to control the visuals of a stock chart.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks about the Perl Excel::Writer::XLSX library but the code and some of the text refers to the Python XlsxWriter library. I'll answer for Python library but the answer is more or less the same for the Perl library.

> How do we change the markers from auto to top/red/diamond, middle/red/circle, and bottom/green/square?

Here is an example:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("chart_stock.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

bold = workbook.add_format({"bold": 1})
date_format = workbook.add_format({"num_format": "dd/mm/yyyy"})

chart = workbook.add_chart({"type": "stock"})

# Add the worksheet data that the charts will refer to.
headings = ["Date", "High", "Low", "Close"]
data = [
    ["2007-01-01", "2007-01-02", "2007-01-03", "2007-01-04", "2007-01-05"],
    [37.21, 35.03, 39.05, 30.34, 38.52],
    [10.49, 19.55, 15.12, 17.84, 16.34],
    [25.45, 23.05, 27.32, 25.45, 27.34],
]

worksheet.write_row("A1", headings, bold)

for row in range(5):
    date = datetime.strptime(data[0][row], "%Y-%m-%d")

    worksheet.write(row + 1, 0, date, date_format)
    worksheet.write(row + 1, 1, data[1][row])
    worksheet.write(row + 1, 2, data[2][row])
    worksheet.write(row + 1, 3, data[3][row])

worksheet.set_column("A:D", 11)

# Add a series for each of the High-Low-Close columns.
chart.add_series(
    {
        "categories": "=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6",
        "values": "=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6",
        "marker": {
            "type": "diamond",
            "size": 10,
            "fill": {"color": "red"},
            "border": {"color": "red"},
        },
    }
)

chart.add_series(
    {
        "categories": "=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6",
        "values": "=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6",
        "marker": {
            "type": "square",
            "size": 10,
            "fill": {"color": "green"},
            "border": {"color": "green"},
        },
    }
)

chart.add_series(
    {
        "categories": "=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6",
        "values": "=Sheet1!$D$2:$D$6",
        "marker": {
            "type": "circle",
            "size": 10,
            "fill": {"color": "red"},
            "border": {"color": "red"},
        },
    }
)


# Add a chart title and some axis labels.
chart.set_title({"name": "High-Low-Close"})
chart.set_x_axis({"name": "Date"})
chart.set_y_axis({"name": "Share price"})

# Turn off the chart legend.
chart.set_legend({"position": "none"})

worksheet.insert_chart("E1", chart, {"x_offset": 10})

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]